# How to raise a matrix to the power of elements in an array that is increasing in an ascending order?

Tags: numpy, matrix, array-broadcasting

Currently I have a C matrix generated by:

```py
def c_matrix(n):
    exp = np.exp(1j*np.pi/n)
    exp_n = np.array([[exp, 0], [0, exp.conj()]], dtype=complex)
    c_matrix = np.array([exp_n**i for i in range(1, n, 1)], dtype=complex)
    return c_matrix
```

What this does is basically generate a list of number from 0 to n-1 using list comprehension, then returns a list of the matrix `exp_n`being raised to the elements of the ascendingly increasing list. i.e.

```
exp_n**[0, 1, ..., n-1] = [exp_n**0, exp_n**1, ..., exp_n**(n-1)]
```

So I was wondering if there's a more numpythonic way of doing it(in order to make use of Numpy's broadcasting ability) like:

```
exp_n**np.arange(1,n,1) = np.array(exp_n**0, exp_n**1, ..., exp_n**(n-1))
```

Comment: you can do exactly what you described in your last code block. 
`exp_n ** np.arange(1, n)` just works. Am I missing something?

Comment: If you want to apply it directly to your matrix, you do need to use broadcasting, as follows: `exp_n[None, :, :] ** np.arange(1, n)[:, None, None]`.

Comment: `exp_n ** np.arange(1, n)` with `exp_n` having a dim of `(2,2)` gives me an error message `ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2,2) (4,) ` though

Comment: You are aware that you go from `1 -> n-1` right? Not from `0`

Comment: yea. Also your `exp_n[None, :, :] ** np.arange(1, n)[:, None, None]` works, it's exactly what I wanted. Also it turns out that `exp_n[None, :] ** np.arange(1, n)[:, None, None]` works too and is a little bit faster. If you put it down as official answer I'll accept it.

Comment: yea i know im going from `1 -> n-1` I'm just concatenating `exp_n**0` after because `python kept taking 0**0 = 1` as matrix element so I can't get Identity matrix for `exp_n**0` lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're speaking of a Vandermonde matrix.  Numpy has `numpy.vander`

---

```
def c_matrix_vander(n):
    exp = np.exp(1j*np.pi/n)
    exp_n = np.array([[exp, 0], [0, exp.conj()]], dtype=complex)
    return np.vander(exp_n.ravel(), n, increasing=True)[:, 1:].swapaxes(0, 1).reshape(n-1, 2, 2)
```

---

***Performance***

```
In [184]: %timeit c_matrix_vander(10_000)
849 µs ± 14.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [185]: %timeit c_matrix(10_000)
41.5 ms ± 549 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

***Validation***

```
>>> np.isclose(c_matrix(10_000), c_matrix_vander(10_000)).all()
True
```

Comment: Amazing. Thanks.

Comment: In any case, there's actually a `exp_n**0` as the first matrix. However the `0` elements in `exp_n` raising to `0` becomes `1` in numpy, so I'd actually get `[[1,1], [1,1]]` instead of the identity. I resolve this issue by `np.concatenate((II, c_matrix_vander(n))` where `II` is the identity matrix. Do you see a better way of doing this?

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to what you mean, because `0**0` *is* `1` mathematically speaking